# $\int\arctan^4(x)\sec^3(x)dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I've tried just about every $u$-substitution I can think of, and I've tried integrating by parts, but I can't seem to get anywhere. I'd appreciate any help at all.

My most recent attempt involved using the identity
$$1+\tan^2x=\sec^2x$$
But after expanding, and using the sum rule for integrals, I tried doing u-substitution by letting $u = \arctan(x)$. However I'm not sure if this is the best approach because I can't find a way to express $\tan(x)$ in terms of u.

Comment: What did you try exactly? Please edit it into the question so we can see where you are stuck.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think there's an answer, meisturtle? Most elementary functions don't have an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: Wolfram doesn't know the answer. Have you tried using $\cos(x)^3 = \cos(3x) + 3 \cos(x)$ and series expansion? Also the fustian has countably infinitely many singularities. Why are you interested in the indefinite integral?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik this is a homework problem and I haven't learned series yet

Comment: This seems like a poorly thought out problem to set for homework since it has no obvious solution.

Comment: @Viktor the *fustian*?

Comment: I wonder if the integrand is supposed to be $\tan^{-4}x\sec^3x$.

Comment: Integrad in simpler form is hard to find a closed-form. $$\int \tan ^{-1}(x) \sec (x) \, dx=2 i \tan ^{-1}\left(e^{-i x}\right) \tan
   ^{-1}(x)+\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{2 (-1)^k e^{-1-2 k} \text{Ei}((1+2
   k) (1-i x))}{2+4 k}-\frac{2 (-1)^k e^{1+2 k} \text{Ei}(-i (1+2 k) (-i+x))}{2+4
   k}\right)+C$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson the function, sorry.

Comment: @GerryMyerson $\tan(x)^{-4}$ seems reasonable. The integral wouldn't be that hard then: $-\frac{(-1 + 3 \cos(2 x))\csc(x)^3}{6}$.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik it is not supposed to be tan(x)^-4

Answer (score 1):

Even using special functions, I do not think that we could obtain the antiderivative. If you want to integrate over a small range (say $0 \leq x \leq \frac \pi 4$), I suppose that series expansion built around $x=0$ could be the only way.

Using a very few terms,
$$\arctan^4(x)\sec^3(x)=x^4+\frac{x^6}{6}+\frac{101 x^8}{120}-\frac{2249 x^{10}}{15120}+\frac{1046861
   x^{12}}{1814400}-\frac{479333 x^{14}}{1478400}+O\left(x^{16}\right)$$ and integrate termwise.

Jus a few result for
$$\int_0^t \arctan^4(x)\sec^3(x)\,dx$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
t & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0.2 & 0.0000643524 & 0.0000643524 \\
 0.3 & 0.000493031 & 0.000493031 \\
 0.4 & 0.00211123 & 0.00211124 \\
 0.5 & 0.00661682 & 0.00661699 \\
 0.6 & 0.0171597 & 0.0171634 \\
 0.7 & 0.0394086 & 0.0394559 \\
 0.8 & 0.083599 & 0.0840325 \\
 0.9 & 0.168305 & 0.171374 \\
 1.0 & 0.326574 & 0.344429
\end{array}
\right)$$ As you can see, it is not good at all for $t>0.8$. For sure, we could improve using more terms.